# Special char indexing and recognition on neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have build a neo4j graph with geo info and indexed it by city toponyms.
Some of toponym has special char or accent marks, typical of the language of the country the place belong to: e.g. Île-de-France or Alajärvi and so on.

If a make search on this index I obtain results only if I write toponym such as it was indexed. There is a way to ignore accent marks, dash or other particular char just to obtain "Île-de-France" simply searching by "ile de france"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a specific analzyer class when the index is first created, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html.

Make sure to have the configured analyzer class (e.g. https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/fr/FrenchAnalyzer.html) on your classpath - it's not distributed with Neo4j.